# Unable to chain second method

Tags: typescript

I am trying to chain multiple methods in a class but getting this error when the second method is chained.

> Property 'welcome' does not exist on type
> 'void'.ts(2339)

class a

```
hello() {
    cy.log('hello');
    return new b();
}
```

class b

```
export class b {
constructor(public readonly element: locator = locator) { }

world(): void {
    cy.log('world');
}
welcome(): void {
    cy.log('welcome');
}
```

class c

```
 a.hello()
  .world()
  .welcome(); //getting error at this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the instance in each method to do that.

```
export class CallPage {
    constructor(public readonly element: locator = locator) { }

    world(): CallPage {
        cy.log('world');
        return this;
    }
    welcome(): CallPage {
        cy.log('welcome');
        return this;
    }
}
```